# replace text, but ignore a certain string inside the document

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a big string: `Hello <span class="ashakd">my</span> name is <bob>!`

I have a second string: `llo my name`

I have what i want to replace it with:`<span class="ashakd">llo my name</span>`

I need to `replace()` it as if the `<span class="ashakd">` and `</span>` didnt exist, but they are replaced with the string so the final result is: `He<span class="ashakd">llo my name</span> is <bob>!`

PS: `<bob>` exists so you cant ignore any text between two >'s it must specifically ignore `<span class="ashakd">` and `</span>`

very sorry if this is confusing. ask me to make it clearer if this is confusing

**edit**

sorry for being unclear, but it must only replace the  within my replace. so if the original string was: `Hello <span class="ashakd">my</span> name is <bob><span class="ashakd">hello</span>!`

the result would be: `He<span class="ashakd">llo my name</span> is <bob><span class="ashakd">hello</span>!`

Comment: very difficult what you trying to say... i can't really understand it :) actually the exist but you want to replace them like they warent there, is this correct ? and is its span every time ?

Comment: Please give us the code you have tried and the output it gives you.

Comment: One thing that is unclear... from the question it sounds like you want to ignore part of the string.  In the question, it doesn't appear as if you want to ignore the <span>, you want to change what is in the <span>.  If that's the case and you know your specific text, treat the span and html as something you identify in the Regex, not ignore.

Comment: i think you have to first make a regex to make the sting clear and than a second one to do what you actually want

Comment: to mattrion: unfortunately i have tried nothing since i know very little regex     to RacerNerd: sorry for the title, it was hard to explain.     to Dwza: span every single time. i want to find a string of text excluding the spans, then i want to replace the text around the spans including them.

Comment: what language are you using ? php / javascript ?

Comment: the language is javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too destructive to the original string, but I propose this solution:

```
var a = 'Hello <span class="ashakd">my</span> name is <bob>!';
var searchString = 'llo my name';
// remove all <span> and </span> tags,  you may not want to remove any and all span tags???
a = a.replace(/<\/?span[^>]*?>/g,'');
a = a.replace(searchString,"<span class='ashakd'>"+searchString+"</span>");
```

What this does is remove all span tags, then search for your "llo my name" search string, and wrap that with a span tag.

Since you said you don't know regex that well, here's a description of:

```
/<\/?span[^>]*?>/g

<\/?   means match on '<' and then optionally a /.  This matches both the start and end tags, i.e. <span...> and </span>

[^>]*?  means match any character that is NOT > in a non-greedy fashion, i.e. stop matching at the first > found.

The final /g means 'global', which means match <span> and </span> as many times as possible.
```

Comment: guess that's not what he wants... yoe need more check... like start pos of searchsting and length of the string and than you have the pos where your insert the span again. so its `he<span.... `

Comment: thanks for this, i think using a few .split() i can make this work. thank you.

Comment: You could also use `var span_matches = a.match(/<\/?span[^>]*?>/g);`, instead of `a.replace` and do something with the span_matches array.